# I can't see the extension methods of LINQ to SQL in Class Library

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, class-library

I created a Class Library named Repository and which includes LINQ To SQL file which stores a ORM of SQL Server Database, besides that I also created another Class Library named Services which has the reference of the Repository class library and I want to use the LINQ to SQL file locating in Repository in Services but I can't see the Extension Methods but I can create an instance of the LinqToSQL in Services.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Repository; // This is the referred class library



namespace Core {
    class BugListService {

        BBDatabaseDataContext dbContext = new BBDatabaseDataContext();

        public int CreateBug(BugList bug) {

            dbContext.BugLists. // <= The extension methods don't appear in intellisense
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I should have added System.Data.Linq namespace to go ahead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add a reference to System.Core? The extension methods for linq live there.

Comment: I've found the solution, I should have referred to `System.Data.Linq`

Comment: Alright, references are so annoying eh ;-)

Comment: Yeap :) I think Visual Studio should be smarter sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you call the extension method like a normal static method? See if you can call:

```
<Declaring Type for the Extension Method>.<Extension Method Name>(bug, <other params>)
```

Might give you some more information about what is going wrong...

Also, you might want to check that you have a Using clause for the exact namespace of the type that declares the extension method, I've had similar issues in the past...